# Trouble with knitting an R-markdown file after changing PC. I can't figure out what i have missed

Tags: r-markdown, render, tinytex

I recently had to change out my work PC (cue lots of dramas). It is a Surface Pro (11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.42 GHz) running Windows 10 Enterprise, OS build 19044.2965.

I re-installed R (4.3.1) and RStudio (2023.06.0 Build 421) and the .rmd files that used to knit, now do not.
Aside: Due to work restrictions I have to download and install packages locally.

When i click the 'Knit' button, I get the following message in the Render tab

```
1/5                  
  2/5 [unnamed-chunk-1]
processing file: CyclesRecordedCorrectedPlot.Rmd
3/5                  
4/5 [Cycle data plot]
5/5                  
    "C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS     CyclesRecordedCorrectedPlot.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output CyclesRecordedCorrectedPlot.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: CyclesRecordedCorrectedPlot.knit.md
Error: LaTeX failed to compile CyclesRecordedCorrectedPlot.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/
  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()
  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org
  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)
  Linux: Use system package manager
```

I thought this meant i was missing 'tinytex' so i tried to install it, and it seemed to be sucessful

> install.packages("tinytex")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/tinytex_0.45.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 136013 bytes (132 KB)
> downloaded 132 KB

> package ‘tinytex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpWURLY3\downloaded_packages

However i still get the same message when i try to knit the .rmd

I have another markdown file, that seems to work without difficuilty

this is what is in the .rmd header

```
title: "Engine Turbine Equivalent Cycles Discrepancies"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    code_folding: hide
  word_document: default
editor_options:
  markdown:
    wrap: 72
```

Can someone help me help myself

I don't fully understand why it worked in the past and why it does not now